# Problem in counting principles from Precalculus by Openstax

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Here is the question:
The set $S$ consists of 900,000,000 whole numbers, each being the same number of digits long. How many digits long is a number from S?(Hint: use the fact that a whole number cannot start with the digit 0).

 What I don't understand is how to take into account the fact that there are $r$ digits in the number, when the first digit can only be between 1-9, and the rest $(r-1)$ digits are between $(0-9)$

 this is how I tried to solve the problem:

#### 1) $S_{size} = 900000000$

#### 2) $9\cdot_{10}N_{r-1} = 900000000$

#### 3) $9\cdot_{10}N_{r-1} = 900000000$

#### 4) $_nC_r = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

#### 5) $_10C_r-1 = \frac{10!}{(r-1)!(10-(r-1))!}$

#### 6) $9\cdot \frac{10!}{(r-1)!(10-(r-1))!} = 900000000$

#### 7) $\frac{3,628,800}{(r-1)!(11-r))!} = 100,000,000$

Answer (score 1):

The cardnality of $S$ is $9 \times 10^8$.

In the first digit, there are $9$ options since it can't begin with $0$, after which we have $10$ options for ther remaining $8$ positions.

The length of the digit is $8+1=9$.